# QGIS Contours plugin

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, contour

I managed to load osm-data with osm2po, pgrouting, postgis and postgresql into qgis.

Then I did a drivingdistance analysis based on cost to finally get the qgis contours plugin up and running.

But when I run it, it doesnt really output "the truth".

I want to get also the cost max-points (in my case 1), but somehow the contours are ending somewhere at 0.7?

What am I doing wrong? please see image attached.
[image]